# What book on TDD for C# with treatment of Mocks

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, mocking

Can you recoment a book on on Unit Testing and TDD for C# with at least some treatment of Mock Objects?

I have seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837/best-books-about-tdd) but it does not seem to mention mocking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The Art of Unit Testing: With Examples in .NET* by Roy Osherove ([Amazon Page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988274), [Official Site](http://www.artofunittesting.com/)) sounds like what you're looking for. He devotes one chapter introducing the concepts of stub and mock objects (using a "roll-your-own" approach), and then a second chapter on using mock object frameworks, particularly [Rhino Mocks](http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx). There is somewhat less emphasis on Test-Driven Development, but there is quite a lot of information about TDD available from other sources, and TDD isn't all that language-specific.

Comment: It's a solid book, and if you're looking for info on Mock's then it's good to know that Roy Osherove is the chief architect of TypeMock

Comment: Roy has a straightforward introduction to the concept. We disagree strongly on where to go after that, but that's another discussion :)

Comment: @Steve, what are the principal sources of discord?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests](http://www.mockobjects.com/book/) by Steve Freeman and 
Nat Pryce - a work in progress, but free online. The code examples are in java, which shouldn't be a problem if you're a C# developer, and does focus extensively on Mocks.

Comment: Due out in the US November 2009.

Comment: Now available ([amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Growing-Object-Oriented-Software-Guided-Tests/dp/0321503627/))

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, Pragmatic Unit Testing in C# with NUnit, 2nd Edition is the best introduction to Unit Testing. It's got a chapter on Mock Objects as well.

Comment: Having written the original paper on Mock Objects (and an upcoming book), I don't this is a good introduction to the concept. They emphasis the isolation of external resources, rather than the effect on the design of the code.

Answer (score 1):

[XUnit Test Patterns](http://xunitpatterns.com/) has a couple of sections on Test Doubles, including Mocks. Not C# specific, but does contain C# examples.

Answer (score -1):

I would highly suggest [Unit Testing: Principles, Practices, and Patterns](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/48927138) by Vladimir Khorikov.

While the book isn't exclusively focused on Test-Driven Development (TDD), it offers invaluable insights into unit testing principles and practices.

The author advocates for the Chicago School of unit tests, contrasting it with the London School (mockist approach). This perspective enriches your understanding of unit testing methodologies. Moreover, the book doesn't merely touch upon theory; it provides practical guidance that proves beneficial in real-world scenarios.

For a comprehensive exploration of unit testing in C# with an emphasis on practical examples and best practices, this book is an excellent resource.

Additionally, based on my own journey after absorbing the concepts from the book, I developed a simple testing library aligned with Test-Driven Development and the Chicago School approach. It might be of interest to you – check out [SUTForge](https://github.com/dovic95/SUTForge).

Comment: This question was asked in 2009, nearly 15 years ago, and only a few months after Stack Overflow was launched. Guidelines were vastly different then. Today this question is 100% off-topic (it's a book recommendation question). Please don't answer off-topic questions. And please don't post an answer promoting your own GitHub repo, as you've also done here.