# Book on Test Driven Development in .NET (using Mocking frameworks)

Tags: c#, .net, tdd, mocking

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Best books about TDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837/best-books-about-tdd)
>   [What book on TDD for C# with treatment of Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880401/what-book-on-tdd-for-c-with-treatment-of-mocks)

Hi, Can anyone suggest a good book on Test driven development in .NET using mocking frameworks? I would like the one which demonstrates the concept by building a sample application step by step ideally using some mocking framework like Moq or Rhino mocks (instead of simply discussing the theory).

Comment: @Martinho, I am aware of the classic books on TDD, but I didn't find much discussion about the mocking frameworks in them

Comment: Ok, here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880401/what-book-on-tdd-for-c-with-treatment-of-mocks. WARNING: If you vote to close as dupe, please pick this one.

Comment: your new link has the exact same question I have asked, but the post is quite old (2 years ago), I would like to wait for any more responses, before closing it and also I am not sure if the book "Art of unit testing" has any case studies in it to build a sample application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking for a fairly specific book. I consider

1. The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET (Roy Osherove)
2. Test Driven Development (Kent Beck)

good books here though.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for quick reply, pls see my comment above

Comment: @RKP: hmmm just realized that The Art of Unit Testing is not on the question I marked as dupe. I know it is mentioned in a similar question, but I'll have to search deeper. Anyways, TAOUT does talk about mocking frameworks and is a very good book. Highly recommend it.

Comment: @RKP: The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET talks about mocking.

Comment: ok, thanks. the book "Art of unit testing" comes close to what I am looking for, but I was waiting to see if there are any more books and my post has been closed before that. not a problem. thanks for the responses.