# Accessing an array from anywhere

Tags: c#, arrays, static

I have a static array which uses a static variable called `Variables.rows` to define the number of rows in the array. `Variables.rows` is defined in another static class called `Variables`.

```
public static class TheArrayClass
{
    public static double[,] HiThere = new double[Variables.rows, 6];
}
```

My problem is that the static array is created **as soon as** the project in run (I believe). This means that the methods needed to assign the correct value to `Variables.Rows` are not executed in time. This means that I get an index error when populating the array because the array does not have the correct size.

I need a way around this so that I can access the array from anywhere in my code please.

Comment: Where is `Variables.Rows` defined?

Comment: And where does the rows property come from, why does the array need to be static?

Comment: HORRIBLE idea to use global variables. Chances are if you're asking how to do it you're new to the language - keep reading, find a way to not use global variables

Comment: @user1920206 Then pass the data to the form when it is create.

Comment: @StenPetrov That is not entirely true, but I can think why you are saying that.

Comment: @lolol Sure - there is, for example, the Singleton design pattern which relies on a globally accessible property. Before user1920206 gets there though he needs to learn how not to use it or it will be abused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that you didn't show where `Variables.Rows` was defined. Either way, you can perform whatever initialization you want in the classe's constructor.

```
public static class TheArrayClass
{
    public static double[,] HiThere;

    static TheArrayClass()
    {
         HiThere = new double[Variables.rows, 6];
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your class is static, a constructor won't work. You will need to create a type initializer (`static TheArrayClass()`). Otherwise, this looks fine.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Whoops! Forgot the `static` keyword.

Comment: @Johnathan-Wood: Type initializers don't support access modifiers. Drop the `public` and you're good.

Answer (score 2):

Try message passing between your forms.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private string _data;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _data = "Some data";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Data = _data;
        form2.Show();
    }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where is he talking about forms?

Comment: @lolol Check the comments on the question. He want to use global static variables to pass data between his forms which is bad practice.

Comment: I can't find the comment but I trust you, I will change my downvote. Sorry.

Comment: @lolol He must have deleted it because my reply is still there. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a design problem, so I'm gonna try to add some information that can help you to solve your problem.

First, a static class is, in fact, created as soon as the project runs. But a static class can also have a static constructor (where you can define the variables.rows) that will also runs one time as soon as the project runs.

Also, maybe you should use an ArrayList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.aspx) or GenericList (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), by doing that you can easily avoid the array variable limitations (like changing its size).

Comment: Yeah, everyone says that global-anything is awful, but unfortunately at the moment I do not have the time to read up much new documentation. Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Man, it is not. Global are dangerous, and because they are dangerous people prefer to avoid it, but they are there for a reason, and the reason is: they are useful. But still, I think there is something wrong in your project.

Comment: @user1920206 take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306106/is-it-bad-form-to-try-and-have-classes-other-than-main-form1-interact-with-each/12306400#12306400

Comment: Please don't suggest that new users use an `ArrayList`.  It shouldn't ever be used by anyone, unless they're forced to as a result of using legacy code.  You should always use `List` instead.  Also note that static classes are *not* created when the project is first run, nor are static constructors run then.  Static constructors are run just before the class is first used, which is when the static class is first initialized.